# Not able to load my resource files using spring mvc web app

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using spring MVC to run my dynamic web application. I am able to write one and run the app successfully. But problem is with loading the resource files like image,JS and CSS. I am getting file Failed to load resource. key point is i am placing the JSP files Outside WEB-INF and Using web logic server.

[image: My App Structure]

My web.xml file

```
<display-name>Support</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>resources/jsp/home.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
   <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
   </servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-servlet.xml,/WEB-INF/spring-jpa.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

my dispathcer servlet

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>    
   <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>  
   <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/resources/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>
```

I have added this in my JSp file

```
<link media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="<spring:url value='resources/css/Map.css' />" type="text/css" />
<spring:url value="resources/css/Mass.css" var="resourceUrl2"/>
<LINK media="screen" rel="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" href="${resourceUrl2}" />
```

Getting the Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404.

any Help???

Update:

What I found with my weblogic server is not able to get the context value for this app. so got the conext path in the jsp file and appended before resources. it worked for me

```
<link media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/css/MaRK.css" type="text/css" />
```

still don't know why spring resources did not work.

Comment: Your url value is wrong... should be **/resource** in the `<spring:url />` to indicate that it should be loaded from the root of the application.

Comment: I have tried that too.'/resources/css/MaRK.css' but no luck.

Comment: The JSP you are requesting is served directly or by the `DispatcherServlet`. One thing to notice is that you are also duplicating your beans you are loading your 'spring-mvc-servlet.xml' twice. Don't do that, it should only be loaded by the `DispatcherServlet`

Comment: Why do you use the `<mvc:resources />` anyway? The resources directory is directly available, so instead of the `<mvc:resources />` tag add the '<mvc:default-servlet-handler />' element.

Comment: i am new to MVC. I am trying to load the jsp files whic are outside WEB-INF. came across this resource tag and added that for fetching the JSP values. how can i load the bean details if i don't have dispather xml file. It will be great if any sample working project u share.

Comment: I removed /WEB-INF/spring-mvc-servlet.xml in my web.xml for duplicate entry.

Comment: @user1268890 Are you able to open your welcome page?

Comment: yes. i am able to open. even my controllers are working. only problem is not able to load static content like JS,CSS and Images.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue and this is how i resolved the issue:
In spring configuration file
Replace

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
With
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```

And provide the below path in the JSP to load static contents

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/Mass.css" type="text/css"/>
```

Hope this will help !

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="resources/"/>
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the following in my JSP, and ran into the same problem:

```html
<link href="/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

After I removed leading `/` from `/css/styles.css` it loaded.

```html
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

I can't explain why. The answers written above did not help me. In fact, I don't even have a `resources` folder at all, all of my static content is placed directly in the `/webapp` folder—and, specifically, in `/css`, `/jsp`, and `/WEB-INF` subdirectories.